# Finding Cases Of Inequality Between Null Space And Solution Set

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$H=(h\in R^m; Ah=0)$ 

 $L=(l \in R^m; Al=b)$

Find a matrix $A^{n*m}$ so:

1. $|L|=0 < |H|=1$
2. $|L|=0 < |H|=\infty$

   3. $|L|=0 < |H|=7$

As for 1. \begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 2 \\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}

as for 2. \begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}

as for 3. I know that if there are the Null space is a vector space therefore if there is one non trivial solution than that vector spans a space and there are infinite solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question 3 requires that your field $F$ should be a finite field.

In particular, letting $F = \Bbb F_7$, we find that the matrix
$$
A = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&0}, \quad b = \pmatrix{0\\1}
$$
Has $L = \emptyset$ and $H = \{(0,t)^T: t \in \Bbb F_7\} \implies |H| = 7$.

Comment: Isn't $A=\begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}$ and $F=Z_7$ is suffiecnt?

Comment: @gbox in that case you'd want $A = 0$ or, if you prefer, $A = \pmatrix{0\\0}$.  Your $A$ would give you $|H| = 49$.

Comment: Got it $7^2$ ways to choose $(x_1,x_2)$, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What is $F^m$? If it is $\mathbb{R}^m$, your argument about infinite solutions is almost correct: there are really infinite solutions, but they do not nescessary span the whole space. For example take a matrix one with space = $\mathbb{R}^2$. The null space is $\{(x, y) | x + 2y = 0\}$, it is not the whole space.

Comment: You are right I will edit the question $F=R$ and it does not span the whole space

Comment: @gbox Just for interest: if you take for vector space  $(\mathbb{Z}/13)^2$ and take matrix one, you will get desired answer: the set of solutions will be $\{(0, 0), (1, 6), (3, 5), (5, 4), (7, 3), (9, 2), (11, 1)\}$

Comment: @ArtemMalykh what about $(2,12)$? You should have $13$ solutions.  Note that each is of the form $(n,6n) \pmod{13}$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Yes, you are right. Your answer provides more correct consideration of finite space :)